# render :layout => false works in development but not production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a landing page where I do not want to render any layouts.  Here is what I have:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :index

  def index
    render :layout => false  
  end
end
```

When I run locally with `rails s`, it works perfectly, however when I push to Heroku and view in production, it still renders the layout.  Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does it render the correct layout in production?

Comment: When you make other changes and push to Heroku, do those changes take effect?

Comment: @ArslanAli - I do not want any layouts to be rendered in production for this view, but it is rendering my application.html.erb layout, but not when I run `rails s`, just in production.

Comment: Could easily be a problem with the deploy. Run in production mode on your machine, see if the issue reproduces itself. `rails s production`. be sure to have a production database created on your machine. Or alter your local config to point to the dev one.

Comment: @linesarefuzzy - Yes...I just tested changing some wording and that change takes fine.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with the files in `config/environments`, or it could be a problem with the deployment process.

One way to try to narrow down differences between development and production environments is to run `rails s -e production`, which will run your local development server in production mode. If that doesn't reproduce the problem, it's probably the deployment. If it does, look in `config/environments` to see what is different between development and production.

Comment: I ran `rails s -e production` and the layout does not render (works just like development).  As far as `config/environments` goes, I haven't modified the file at all, so everything that is there was generated automatically.